# Mostrar datos del dia de hoy mas 1 semana adelante en mysql

Tags: mysql

Buenos dias/tardes/noches.
Tengo una tabla en mysql que tiene un campo datetime current_timestamp, nombre: FechaCarga.
Lo que necesito es mostrar los registros donde la fecha de carga este contemplada entre el dia actual y 7 dias en adelante ya que los registros se cargan en una agenda y lo que me falta mostrar es la caducidad de ese dato que se cargo "En estos 7 dias caducan los siguientes registros..." y mostrarlos, siempre tomando como fecha de inicio la fecha actual y fecha de fin, fecha actual + 7 dias.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para calcular un semana despues de la actual puedes usar:

```
NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Como **NOW()** te devuelve la fecha y la hora, para recoger solo la fecha puedes usar:

```
CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Usado en una consulta sería tal que así:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN CURDATE() and CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY;
```

Te mostrará los registros en un intervalo desde el día actual hasta siete días después.

> EDICIÓN (explicación)

La función **NOW()** recupera la fecha y hora un formato: **yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss**, por lo que `SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN NOW() and NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY;` el OrderDate que buscaría sería desde **yyyy-MM-dd(hoy) hh:mm:ss** hasta **yyyy-MM-dd(hoy+7) hh:mm:ss** por lo que sí grabaron un dato con una hora por ejemplo *08:25:05* y al realizar consulta la realizas a las *08:25:06* ese registro no sería encontrado, por consiguiente y como dijo @PatricioMoracho en el comentario. La opción más correcta para este problema de mostrar solo siete días más es usar **CURDATE()**

Comment: El op indicó que el campo en la tabla es del tipo date/time, No sería conveniente entonces quitar la parte horaria del mismo para usar el `BETWEEN`? En tu ejemplo sería `OrderDate`

Comment: tu respuesta es muy confusa es now o curdate?

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho, la indicación que dio a conocer fue **"Tengo una tabla en mysql que tiene un campo datetime current_timestamp"**, este campo recoge la fecha y la hora por lo que le he dado dos opciones que puede o no usar **NOW()** daría un formato *fecha-hora* mientras que **CURDATE()** solo recogería la *fecha*. Cabe destacar que solo le interesan los días y tu opción de quitar la franja horaria es lo más correcto.

Comment: Hola @JackNavaRow, ambas opciones funcionan, el **NOW()** contabiliza también las horas por lo que si lo comparas `SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN NOW() and NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY;` empezaría a contar el día de hoy en la hora actual hasta siete días después en la hora actual, por otro lado, si usas el **CURDATE()** solo tendrá en cuenta la fecha del día actual, en la consulta estaría entre hoy y dentro de siete días sin contabilizar las horas.

Comment: lo se , pero recuerda que se haces una respuesta trata de explicar una sola o las dos por separado los usuario que no sepan mysql los confundiras todo

Comment: @JackNavaRow, Vale. Gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Hol @Edu, te doy un ejemplo: si en tu caso `OrderDate` vale `2017-08-24 11:45:00 am` y buscas hasta `2017-08-24` ese dato no te lo va a mostrar. En mi experiencia cuando un usuario busca hasta una fecha, espera ver los registros de esa fecha aunque sean de cualquier horario.  Lo que digo es que debieras quitar la parte horaria de `OrderDate` para que funcione adecuadamente.